# swapoff is not permanent

Tags: swap

I'm in the middle of expanding the size of my Ubuntu VM and I'm reading [these](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1007907) instrctions from VMware. One of the steps is to run `swapoff` and reboot to check the new partition table. `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda` gives me the exact same partition table as before. So, either the people at VMware Player are using a different Linux system or they don't know what they're talking about. What's the equivalent command to achieve what their instructions are telling me to do?

Answer (score 0):

`swapoff` is not permanent, it's just for temporarily unmounting the swap in case you need to mess around with swap partitions.

The bit that changes the partition table is the bit that says,

> going to fdisk /dev/sdX , delete Linux partition (type 83), recreate a new partition larger in size leaving space for the swap partition, and quit.

Note: this is a fairly dangerous thing to do; I would not advise doing this unless you had good backups and knew quite a bit about partitions and filesystems.

Also remember to resize the filesystem with `resize2fs` later.

Comment: Well is there any reason why VMware seems to think it is?

Comment: Sorry, didn't see you'd linked the instructions. I've edited answer. Unfortunately I think the instructions are a little hard to follow and assume you are already very proficient.

Comment: How is this dangerous? If the instructions are followed properly and nothing important is unplugged, then will anything still get out of whack?

Comment: It involves manually resizing a partition by deleting it and recreating it with another size, then running tune2fs.  If you do this wrong you could corrupt the partition or lose data.  There are other tools that offer more friendly, automated ways of resizing partitions. gparted comes to mind if you have a graphical interface.

Comment: No GUI. It's a minimal installation.